# Problem with google webmasters site performance review

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-optimization

I noticed that i have not being getting traffic via google organic searches. I decided to find out what the problem may be, and i registered on Google webmasters.

From what i saw, it seems my site is not Google friendly:

```
Performance overview (from google webmasters) as at august 12, 2011
On average, pages in your site take 16.9 seconds to load 
(updated on Aug 12, 2011). This is slower than 99% of sites
```

Not satisfied with that, i decided to check rating on other speed test platforms and below are the results

```
Summary (from http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/#url=myjobmag.com_2Findex.php&mobile=false)
The page Jobs In Nigeria, Vacancies in Nigeria... 
got an overall Page Speed Score of 92 (out of 100). Learn more

97/100 (from firebug page speed)

Website information (from pingdom)

Total loading time:
    2.5 seconds
Total objects:
    18 (189.8 KB)
External objects:
    3 (83.6 KB)
```

My problem is:

1. Whats the reason for the wide gap between the google webmasters view of page speed and other page speed test analytics
2. How can i improve the google webmasters page speed analysis as it may be affecting my page indexing adversely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that at the time Google crawled the site your hosting was experiencing some difficulties.

If that pattern continues consider using a web-caching service like CloudFlare (free and fairly easy to set up) which should speed up loading time.